# Cache data server side for ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, caching

I'm using [TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and [Instagram-PHP-API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) to request data from both APIs on my server, concatenate them into an array and build this into JSON which I can consume on the client with a simple GET request in jQuery.

This is all working fine, however it is quite slow. When I make a request to static JSON data as a test, it is far quicker. It seems the php script on my server to get this data is running each time (so starting with an empty array, using the wrappers the libraries provide to make requests etc.). What I would like to do is to cache/store this data, and only make another request once or twice a day.

My PHP knowledge is not the best so I'm sure there is a relatively simple way of doing this.

Here is the php script on my server:

```
<?php

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
require_once('Instagram.php');

unset($allFeeds);
$allFeeds = array();

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "XXXX' => "XXXX",
'consumer_key' => "XXXX",
'consumer_secret' => "XXXX"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=XXX';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$twitter_response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url,$requestMethod)->performRequest();


$jsonTweets = json_decode($twitter_response);

foreach ($jsonTweets as $tweet) {

 $tweetObj = new stdClass();
 $tweetObj->type = 'Twitter';
 $tweetObj->created_at = strtotime($tweet->created_at);
 $tweetObj->text = $tweet->text;
 $allFeeds[] = $tweetObj;
}

use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
 'apiKey'      => 'XXXX',
 'apiSecret'   => 'XXXX',
 'apiCallback' => 'XXXX'
));

$token = 'XXX';
$code = $token;
$instagram->setAccessToken($code);

$id_one = 'XXX';
$id_two = 'XXX';

$insta_response_one = $instagram->getUserMedia($id_one, 20);
$insta_response_two = $instagram->getUserMedia($id_two, 10);

foreach ($insta_response_one->data as $insta_one) {
 $instaObjOne = new stdClass();
 $instaObjOne->type = 'Instagram One';
 $instaObjOne->created_at = (int)$insta_one->created_time;

  if (isset($insta_one->caption->text)) {
   $instaObjOne->text = $insta_one->caption->text;
  }

$instaObjOne->img = $insta_one->images->standard_resolution->url;
$allFeeds[] = $instaObjOne;

}

foreach ($insta_response_two->data as $insta_two) {
 $instaObjTwo = new stdClass();
 $instaObjTwo->type = 'Instagram Two';
 $instaObjTwo->created_at = (int)$insta_two->created_time;
 if (isset($insta_two->caption->text)) {
   $instaObjTwo->text = $insta_two->caption->text;
 }
$instaObjTwo->img = $insta_two->images->standard_resolution->url;
 $allFeeds[] = $instaObjTwo;
}

function dateSort($a, $b) {
 return $b->created_at - $a->created_at;
}

usort($allFeeds, "dateSort");

$data = json_encode($allFeeds);

// cache $data here?

echo $data;

?>
```

I bringing it into my frontend like so:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
  url: 'path/to/script.php'
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data) {
  // do stuff with data here
  });
}
```

Hope that makes sense, thanks

Comment: It's as simple as putting `file_put_contents('cache.txt',$data)` where you want to cache the result and then at the top you would check the current time and compare with the last time the file was modified. Something like `if ((time() - filemtime('cache.txt')) > 24 * 60 * 60) { echo file_get_contents('cache.txt');exit(); }`. This is if you want the data to be refetched if it is >24 hours old.

Comment: Note the usage of `exit()` so the api request is skipped if a valid cache file exists.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I've noticed this doesn't speed up the ajax request up much though...guess I'll have to cache it on the client in some way for that

Comment: Np... By the way, I messed up when I wrote my comment above. It should have been a less than sign when you compare the time the file was modified. I fixed this in my answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to add caching to your code.

It's using `file_put_contents('cache.txt',$data)` to cache the request data and then at the top of the file it checks the current time and compares with the last time the file was modified. If it was modified less than 24 hours ago, it just outputs the content of the cache file using `echo file_get_contents('cache.txt);` and stops the script.

```
<?php

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

// Check if file was modified less than 24 hours ago
if ((time() - filemtime('cache.txt')) < 24 * 60 * 60) { 

    // Output contents of cache file and stop script
    echo file_get_contents('cache.txt');
    exit(); 
}

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
require_once('Instagram.php');

unset($allFeeds);
$allFeeds = array();

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "XXXX" => "XXXX",
'consumer_key' => "XXXX",
'consumer_secret' => "XXXX"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=XXX';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$twitter_response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url,$requestMethod)->performRequest();


$jsonTweets = json_decode($twitter_response);

foreach ($jsonTweets as $tweet) {

 $tweetObj = new stdClass();
 $tweetObj->type = 'Twitter';
 $tweetObj->created_at = strtotime($tweet->created_at);
 $tweetObj->text = $tweet->text;
 $allFeeds[] = $tweetObj;
}

use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
 'apiKey'      => 'XXXX',
 'apiSecret'   => 'XXXX',
 'apiCallback' => 'XXXX'
));

$token = 'XXX';
$code = $token;
$instagram->setAccessToken($code);

$id_one = 'XXX';
$id_two = 'XXX';

$insta_response_one = $instagram->getUserMedia($id_one, 20);
$insta_response_two = $instagram->getUserMedia($id_two, 10);

foreach ($insta_response_one->data as $insta_one) {
 $instaObjOne = new stdClass();
 $instaObjOne->type = 'Instagram One';
 $instaObjOne->created_at = (int)$insta_one->created_time;

  if (isset($insta_one->caption->text)) {
   $instaObjOne->text = $insta_one->caption->text;
  }

$instaObjOne->img = $insta_one->images->standard_resolution->url;
$allFeeds[] = $instaObjOne;

}

foreach ($insta_response_two->data as $insta_two) {
 $instaObjTwo = new stdClass();
 $instaObjTwo->type = 'Instagram Two';
 $instaObjTwo->created_at = (int)$insta_two->created_time;
 if (isset($insta_two->caption->text)) {
   $instaObjTwo->text = $insta_two->caption->text;
 }
$instaObjTwo->img = $insta_two->images->standard_resolution->url;
 $allFeeds[] = $instaObjTwo;
}

function dateSort($a, $b) {
 return $b->created_at - $a->created_at;
}

usort($allFeeds, "dateSort");

$data = json_encode($allFeeds);

// Cache $data here
file_put_contents('cache.txt', $data);

echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: ^ Just tried again and it is significantly better. Stupidly I had the if statement after the requests were being made. Cheers.